# APK Invalid Signature

Tags: java, android, air, google-play, flash-builder

I'm receiving the error below when uploading my APK to the Google Play Store. My app is built with Flash Builder 4.16.1 w/Air 29. My last published version was from two weeks ago and I've had dozens of builds uploaded with no issues, so this is new. I've updated both JAVA and my Flash Builder IDE, but it did not help.

> Error: Upload failed You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature
>   (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer
>   CERT.RSA): Failed to parse JAR signature META-INF/CERT.RSA:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateException: Failed to parse certificate #1

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816305/upload-new-apk-to-alpha-failed

Comment: This is currently being fixed by Google. Please check:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2482446

Comment: The possible duplicate is for Android Studio, which has a solution. This issue is for Flash Builder, which does not have the ability to select V1/V2 signatures currently.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select V1 and V2, both the versions of signatures while signing the Apk. 
V1 - Jar Signature. 
v2 - Full Apk signature.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bad rollout on Google's behalf. They fixed it now, our uploads finally work after a week of frustration!