# Error from PlayStore with VS (Xamarin) signed APK

Tags: android, xamarin, package, manifest

When I try to upload my APK to Google Play I get this error:

Error from apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_MANIFEST: Missing META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

If it isn't one thing, it's something else. I feel I'm going in circles with this, which should be a wizard.

The package is Release mode. It is signed. There is a Manifest.

None of the errors I get give the slightest hint at how to fix them. SIGH.

Comment: Are you using the same signing identity as you did before while uploading to playstore?

Comment: Please refer to this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816305/upload-new-apk-to-alpha-failed

Comment: I believe i'm using the same signing identity. I'll probably just create a new project, new name, new keystore, etc. and see if that works. It's very frustrating to spend so much more time trying to upload a file than to create the file and test it out (well, almost). I mean, this calls for a wizard.

Comment: Actually, the thing is once you sign an app with a signing identity on play store it will only accept the same app with that signing identity

Comment: I haven't even gotten that far. I have the signed APK and just want to upload it. But from what I can tell no one has a clue what to do with this error, what it means(the app has a manifest file), or anything. I'm using VS 2017. The apk will run on my phones. This error report occurs before (I think) the app is uploaded.