# Create new keystore for new application release

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-console-developer

I want to release a new application. And I have created a keystore specifically for that application. When on the Google console I accidentally clicked on enabling Google Play App Signing. My APK upload failed because it did not match the application signer. I have long lost the application keystore before. How can I release a new application with a new keystore? Explanation from Google makes me even more confused, can I give me the order that I have to do.

**My error on console looks like this:**

[image]

**And the upload certificate section is written like this:**

> Your application does not have an upload certificate. The certificate
>   you use to sign the first APK will be used as an upload certificate.

Comment: if you have lost the keystone then change the package name and generate new keystore.

Comment: This new application already has the new name package, and the new keystore I have created. The problem is when I want to release a product and upload the apk the result is failed because it uploaded with an invalid signature

Comment: If *YOU* created a new keystore for a new app you have to follow the steps for [Google Play App Signing](https://youtu.be/PuaYhnGmeEk) as if you are migrating an existing app to App Signing. The alternate is to the use the key Google Play generates to sign your app for upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While generating signed APK, Just check on Both signatures version i.e

Comment: Both of them are different of course, i need google play console accepting my apk with new keystore

Comment: Thanks, i just realize this is perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

I want confirmation that I have found the answer, via this link 
[[Android Signed APK showing as Unsigned APK when trying to upload to production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605171/android-signed-apk-showing-as-unsigned-apk-when-trying-to-upload-to-production/42805659][1])
I have to check both options when generating a signed APK.

> There are three choices available to us:
>
> select V1 (For older version of signing) - apk gets uploaded
>   successfully
>
> select V2 (For newer version of signing) - Please note that selecting
>   this alone will not work.
>
> select V1 and V2 (For older and newer version) - apk gets uploaded
>   successfully
>
> Why selecting V2 alone does not work ?
>
> Because APK Signature Scheme v2 was introduced in Android 7.0
>   (Nougat). To make a APK installable on Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) and
>   older devices, the APK should be signed using JAR signing before being
>   signed with the v2 scheme.

thank you for participating in helping find answers